# Protect critical resource tables in a CTE (WITH clause)

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, common-table-expression

I'm using an intermediate table that I update to make sure no other concurrent action can be processed on a critical tables that must not be accessed concurrently.

Transaction 1

```
BEGIN
UPDATE locktable
/* Do some stuff */
...
COMMIT
```

Concurrent transaction 2

```
BEGIN
Update locktable
/* Do some other stuff */
...
COMMIT
```

This way I'm sure Transaction 1 and Transaction 2 are atomic.

I changed my code to a WITH clause statement for simplification and performance reasons.
I'm wondering if I can guarantee operation atomicity the same way with CTEs.

CTE simplified Example:

Transaction 1

```
WITH 

lock_op AS (
UPDATE locktable
...
RETURNING id),

some_stuff AS
(
/* Do insert and update operations with RETURNING clause*/
...
)

SELECT * 
FROM some_stuff
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM lock_op)
```

Concurrent transaction 2

```
WITH 

lock_op AS (
UPDATE locktable
...
RETURNING id),

other_stuff AS
(
/* Do insert and update operations with RETURNING clause*/
...
)

SELECT * 
FROM other_stuff
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM lock_op)
```

Basically, I'm wondering if "SELECT 1 FROM lock_op" is initiated before any INSERT and UPDATE from some_stuff and other_stuff and hence, is protecting my critical data for the time being of the transaction delimited by the WITH scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the same ordering guarantees here. There's no promise
that `lock_op`'s query will execute before `some_stuff`'s.

Otherwise it's reasonably OK. The row lock is taken in `lock_op` and held until the implicit transaction that wraps the CTE (if you don't use explicit begin/commit) is committed.

To get such an ordering guarantee you could use a subquery-in-FROM with an `OFFSET 0`, or you could make the query in `some_stuff` directly depend on `lock_op` to ensure it's evaluated first.

Personally I'd leave it how it was, maybe with a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` instead of an `UPDATE` if you can to reduce MVCC row churn.

---

For other readers, it's important to note that this poster is NOT assuming that somehow doing things in a single statement makes them happen atomically, immune from concurrency effects. That assumption would be *absolutely wrong*. CTEs are not magic concurrency-fixing sauce.

You must use row or table locking or (with care and understanding) use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation + a retry loop.

The simplest approach is to `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` in the transaction that makes the changes. This permits concurrent reads, but not writes.

For finer grained locking use a subquery or CTE term with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear answer. I think I will go for an hybrid solution implementing two distinct requests: 1/ one for locking the lock_op table and 2/ another one for the CTE. Both within a single transaction. My CTE contains many commands that need to be globally atomic for cohrency reasons and (if I understood properly) the SELECT FOR UPDATE will only guarantee individual operations to be preserved from concurrent accesses / changes.

Comment: If you need global isolation, consider an advisory lock. It should be much cheaper than `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`-ing some 1-row lock table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know advisory locks. It could possibly meet my requirements since all the operations I need to isolate are linked to a given single id that I can provide to the pg_advisory_lock function.

Comment: Just correcting myself. Advisory locks do not meet my requirements since they use a global id that blocks any other request refering to the same id although I just want to block a specific operation for a specific user.